# What is this? CStr("DELETE")

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I'm working on an older VB.Net project, and I'm finding hundreds of places where either string literals or string variables are being CStr'd. It is also being done with Ints as well. Is there some value to this that I am unaware of? Is this an actual operation that costs processing power?

Comment: Bizarre. Is the result being used in any way?

Comment: Don't really see that to much but if you look at the Microsoft information it appears to enhance performance. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx      - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch47ss2a.aspx

Comment: ToString() is an actual method invocation, if performed on a string, it might actually be worse. EDIT: confirmed.

Comment: @coder32 - you missed the point. That article is stating the `CStr` improves performance *when compared to* other casting options like `ToString` but in this case it is completely redundant

Comment: @Zaggler - Option Strict On/Off makes no difference to this `CStr` returns a string `"DELETE"` already *is* a string so the Type Inference would be exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CStr** on a string is completely redundant, and not harmful.

I built a file:

```
Sub Main()
   Dim result = CStr("string")

    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub
```

and the compiler was clever enough to replace CStr("string") with "string" if you have a look at the disassembled assembly with ILSpy.

Comment: It will do exactly the same thing, to the compiler they're both just strings.

Comment: I didn't even realize we were talking about inference, it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Zaggler - `"12"` *is* a string so why would you want it to be an integer at some later point in time? Type Inference using `Option Infer` which I think is what you are referring to when you say let the compiler do the casting does not cause any detrimental side effects it just removes the requirement to put `As SomeType`. However `CStr("abc")` is completely pointless